# Generating TailwindCSS safelist with function?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm attempting to generate a safelist for TailWindCSS 3.0.23 using a function so I can cover some ranges.

For some reason, the classes still seem to be purged.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./app/**/*.php', './resources/**/*.{php,vue,js}'],

  safelist: function(){
    let list = [
      'user-administrator:not(.wp-admin)',
    ];

    for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5 ){
      list[list.length] = 'opacity-' + i;
    }

    return list;
  },
```

Is this type of thing possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding a pair of parenthesis after the closing bracket of the function so it executes.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./app/**/*.php', './resources/**/*.{php,vue,js}'],

  safelist: function(){
    let list = [
      'user-administrator:not(.wp-admin)',
    ];

    for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5 ){
      list[list.length] = 'opacity-' + i;
    }

    return list;
  }(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could the following code in `javascript`.

```
const tailwindColors = require("./node_modules/tailwindcss/colors")
const colorSafeList = []

// Skip these to avoid a load of deprecated warnings when tailwind starts up
const deprecated = ["lightBlue", "warmGray", "trueGray", "coolGray", "blueGray"]

for (const colorName in tailwindColors) {
  if (deprecated.includes(colorName)) {
    continue
  }

  // Define all of your desired shades
  const shades = [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]

  const pallette = tailwindColors[colorName]

  if (typeof pallette === "object") {
    shades.forEach((shade) => {
      if (shade in pallette) {
       // colorSafeList.push(`text-${colorName}-${shade}`)  <-- You can add different colored text as well 
        colorSafeList.push(`bg-${colorName}-${shade}`)
      }
    })
  }
}

// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  safelist: colorSafeList,                      // <-- add the safelist here
  content: ["{pages,app}/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: tailwindColors,
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./app/**/*.php', './resources/**/*.{php,vue,js}'],
  safelist: [
    'user-administrator:not(.wp-admin)',
    ...Array.from(Array(21).keys()).map((x) => `opacity-${x * 5}`)
  ],
}
```